# I cannot get grep to print results

Tags: bash, grep, syntax

Total noob here. I am blindly stumbling my way through bash. I realize that there is a syntax error in the following script but, I cannot figure it out. The script just sits there.

```
#!/bin/bash

mac=`tail -F ~/scripts/scan.txt | grep -i "IP:" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1` 

sudo dhcpdump -i wlan0 > ~/scripts/scan.txt
echo $mac
```

Thanks for any help. I am gonna feel like an idiot when I find out.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? the `-F` option of `tail` is probably not something you want in a variable assignment as it as it will block waiting for bytes to be appended to the file.

Comment: Also change the order of lines, in the first line you are reading a file that does not exist yet (probably, as per script)..it will be generated by the second line (if not exist already)..

Comment: What is the content of `~/scripts/scan.txt`? Give me a ping with @A.B.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, scan.txt is being continually monitored by scan -F, which never quits. Secondly, grep "IP:" fails - try "IP" instead, & thirdly you're generating the scan.txt file after you've checked it..

You'd need to have the dhcpdump line running as a timed process to make the first program line do anything at all.